# Can you parse an XML into R Shiny and view as a data frame?

Tags: r, xml, dataframe, shiny

I'm new to R-shiny and I'm trying to develop an R-shiny application that would allow the user to upload an XML file, view the table as a data frame, and then download it as a CSV.

I've so far had no luck anywhere trying to find info on parsing XML's into R-shiny. Below is some code that I found from someone else's post on here which allows you to read in an XML and it will display the raw text, but I'm looking to get a proper data frame so that I can do some analysis on the data that the user uploads.

```
library(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
    fileInput("File", "Choose file"),
    tableOutput("Data")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    Data <- eventReactive(input$File, {
        read_xml(input$File$datapath)
        
    })
    
    output$Data <- renderTable({
        head(xml_text(Data()))
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The code to do what I need in R is very simple, but converting this over to R-shiny is causing me lots of trouble.

```
data <- xmlParse("C:/filepath/data.xml")

df <- xmlToDataFrame(data, nodes =getNodeSet(data, "//nm:Row",
                                             namespaces=c(nm = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet")))
```

Can anyone help please?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use package `XML`the same way you do in base R:

```
library(shiny)
library(XML)

ui <- fluidPage(
    fileInput("File", "Choose file"),
    tableOutput("Data")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    df <- eventReactive(input$File, {
        xmlToDataFrame(input$File$datapath)
    })
    
    output$Data <- renderTable( head( df()))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the response! Sorry I should have mentioned that the XML I need to access has several nodes, so using xmlToDataFrame in the way you have suggested yields the error "Duplicate subscripts for columns". In order to produce a data frame in base R I need to use the code displayed in the second chunk of code in the question, have you got any idea how I could use this in shiny? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Update: I've managed to solve the issue by writing a function that converts the "table" node of the xml into a data frame, and calling this function from within the server.

```
converter <- function(xml_data){
    data <- xmlParse(xml_data)
    df <- xmlToDataFrame(data, nodes =getNodeSet(data, "//nm:Row",
                                                 namespaces=c(nm = "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet")))
    colnames(df) <- df[1,]
    df <- df[-1, ]
    return(df)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
    fileInput("File", "Choose file"),
    tableOutput("Data")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    df <- eventReactive(input$File, {
        converter(input$File$datapath)
    })
    
    output$Data <- renderTable( head( df()))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```